# Should I use a cursor for this?

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I have a table with three fields. Group number, X-coord and Y-coord. There can be from 0 to about 10 rows within each group number.

What I want to do is calculate the maximum and minimum distance between points within each group. Obviously, this will only give you a value if there are 2 or more rows within that group.

Output should consist of fields: group number, minDistance, maxDistance.

Is a cursor a good solution for this?

(Coordinates are in WGS84 and I have a working formula for calculating distances)

My reasoning for using a cursor is that I cannot avoid doing a cross join for each group and then applying the formula for each result of the cross join.

Comment: which Version of SQL-Server do you use?

Comment: do you want to compare x and y coordinates with the ones from the previous record to calculate the distance as first step and then find the min and max?

Comment: I need to compare all coordinates with all other coordinates within the same group.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a cursor in your situation but preferably a scalar User Defined Function with the required group number in argument, and calculate the maximum distance for that group inside the UDF.

Please note the calculation algorithm inside the function is much simpler than what you may have.

```
create table dist (groupId int, X int, Y int)
insert into dist(groupid, x, y) values (1,14,20),(1,11,20),(1,10,22),(1,12,24),(1,11,28),(1,19,78)
insert into dist(groupid, x, y) values (2,10,20),(2,11,20),(2,10,22),(2,12,24),(2,11,28),(2,17,52)

create function dbo.getMinMaxDistanceForGroup (@groupId int)
    returns table as return (
        select MIN(SQRT(SQUARE(b.X - a.X) + SQUARE(b.Y - a.Y))) MinDistance, 
               MAX(SQRT(SQUARE(b.X - a.X) + SQUARE(b.Y - a.Y))) MaxDistance
                from dist a cross join dist b 
                where a.groupId = @groupId and b.groupId = @groupId
    )

select groupId, MinDistance, MaxDistance 
from dist OUTER APPLY dbo.getMinMaxDistanceForGroup(groupId) 
group by groupid, MinDistance, MaxDistance
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, there is a large number of groups. Won't I need a cursor in order to run the UDF on all the groups?

Comment: you would use an outer query with distinct groupId and use the APPLY -Operator to run the function for each groupId

Comment: @Vandrer : I added the line for selecting each group and the max distance for that group... Does it answer your question ?

Comment: I tested your approach on my data set, but it did end up being slower than my cursor implementation. One reason for this is that I had to create two functions. One for the minimum value and one for the maximum value.

When using a cursor, I use a table that I empty for each iteration. Then I insert all the distanses for the current group into the table and select the max and min from it.

Comment: It should run faster than a cursor returning both MIN and MAX values in an inline table UDF, then using an outer apply to apply to all your groups !